# Use Range.Find to Find Multiple Values in Different Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to find the row index for the row that has both "Tuning Range" "Test-Config" and then repeat the process but find the row index for the row that has both "Tuning Range" "FunctionalTest"

Here is what I have for my code so far. When it run it, it works for the line `rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "Tuning Range", "Test-Config")` but then presents this next line to have the value of 0 `rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Tuning Range", "FunctionalTest")`. I also added message boxes in `Function getrowindex` to see if it was running all the way through and I cannot get my second `Set` statement message box to appear only the first, so it appears that this entire portion of the code does not output anything.

```
Set parameter_row = Worksheets(WDnum).Range("C:C").Find(What:=routingname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not parameter_row.EntireRow.Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
        getrowindex = parameter_row.Row
    MsgBox "Row value" & getrowindex
    Exit Function
    End If
```

---

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Range, dict As Object, sysrow As Integer, sysnum As String, wsName As String
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim SDtab As Worksheet
Dim Value As Long, colindex As Long, rowindex As Long, rowindex_1 As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("Q:\QSpecification and Configuration Document.xlsx")
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each i In ws.Range("E2:E15").Cells 
        sysnum = i.Value
        sysrow = i.Row
        syscol = i.Column

    If sysnum = "" Then
    End If
If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then ' check if unique value already exists before adding it to dictionary
    dict.Add sysnum, True
    If Not SheetExists(sysnum, ThisWorkbook) Then
        wsName = i.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value 
        If SheetExists(wsName, wbSrc) Then 
            wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).Copy After:=ws 
            wb.Worksheets(wsName).name = sysnum 
        End If
        
 Sheets(1).Select
colindex = getcolumnindex(ws, "Tuning Range")
Value = getjiradata(ws, sysrow, colindex)

rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "Tuning Range", "Test-Config")
rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Tuning Range", "FunctionalTest")

    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet " & sysnum & " already exists"
    End If
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

---

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook)
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

---

```
Function getcolumnindex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) 
Dim paramname As Range
Set paramname = sht.Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:=colname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not paramname Is Nothing Then
        getcolumnindex = paramname.Column
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Function getjiradata(sht As Worksheet, WDrow As Integer, parametercol As Long) 
    getjiradata = sht.Cells(WDrow, parametercol)
End Function
```

---

```
Function getrowindex(WDnum As Variant, parametername As String, routingname As String) As Long 
Dim parameter_row As Range

Set parameter_row = Worksheets(WDnum).Range("B:B").Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not parameter_row.EntireRow.Find(What:=routingname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
        getrowindex = parameter_row.Row
    MsgBox "Parameter row value is " & getrowindex
Exit Function
    End If
Set parameter_row = Worksheets(WDnum).Range("C:C").Find(What:=routingname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not parameter_row.EntireRow.Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
        getrowindex = parameter_row.Row
    MsgBox "Row value" & getrowindex
    Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```vb
'In sheet `WDNum`, find the row with `parametername` in ColB and `routingname` in ColC
'  return zero if not match found
Function getrowindex(WDnum As Variant, parametername As String, routingname As String) As Long
    Dim parameter_row As Range, ws As Worksheet, f As Range, addr As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WDnum)
    
    Set f = ws.Columns("B").Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address 'remember the first cell found
    Do While Not f Is Nothing
        If f.Offset(0, 1).Value = routingname Then 'check col C value
            getrowindex = f.row
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set f = ws.Columns("B").FindNext(after:=f) 'find the next match
        If f.Address = addr Then Exit Do 'exit if we've looped back around
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: I tried your approach, however when I check the values of `rowindex` and `rowindex_1` it appear that `rowindex` shows the correct value of 29 but `rowindex_1` still shows 0 when it should be 276

Comment: Works fine for me in testing: maybe your data doesn't contain an exact match?

Comment: I got it. I am not sure why it wasnt working when I first ran it. Is there a way to run if say I wanted to check in Column B and Column E other than changing the Offset number to be 3? Also in your note what do you mean by remember the first cell found? is that referring to the cell found in column B? So it can be used when finding Column C value

Comment: `Find()` and `FindNext()` will loop back to the first cell found once it has found the last cell in the search range.  You need that `If f.Address = addr Then Exit Do` to avoid getting stuck in an endless loop.  If you need the search columns to be varaible then add a couple more parameters to the function so you can specify the column numbers or letters.

Comment: Oh I see, so it will keep looping through Column B for Tuning Range and then it will loop through all the tuning ranges and search in Column C for Test-Config row that corresponds with Tuning Range. Then it will repeat the process with the second line of `rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Tuning Range", "FunctionalTest")` since it calls the same function

Comment: I have marked the ones that worked for the case in question. I do not have the abilities to up or down vote.